# can't import NumPy Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, numpy

I searched around and I haven't solve my questions. So plz help me. Thanks!
I want to install HTSeq, and it requires Python 2.5 (or later) and NumPy.
I have installed Xcode 4.2.1 before, my OS is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2.
When the installations of Python(2.7.2) and NumPy(numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg)  finished, I ran Python, and tried to import numpy, it appeared as follows:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.


>>> import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Comment: It looks like you have installed the wrong numpy package.

Comment: Hi tal, thanks for your reply. I downloaded numpy package(.dmg format) from SciPy.org(http://www.scipy.org/Download, and it's for python 2.7. I don't know what's wrong with it. According to your comment, which numpy package should I install? Thank you!                ------pythonperlr

Comment: The dmg you are trying is for OS 10.3 judging by the name, and I am guessing it doesn't contain 64 bit support and whatever you need for 10.7. I haven't installed numpy on Lion (I am still running Snow Leopard), so I can't tell you which version. But you clearly need a different version from the one you are trying

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing out the question. I am new to Mac, my OS X Lion was pre-installed. Thank you very much.--pythonperlr

Comment: OSX Lion does include numpy as part of the Apple installed python

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as well: Mac OS 10.7.3, freshly downloaded Python 2.7.2 from python.org, and numpy 1.6.1 via scipy.org, specifically the version for Python 2.7. I got the exact same error message as the original poster.

I believe this has to do with "architecture" issues--that the numpy .dmg download from sourceforge is 32-bit, and python defaults to 64-bit when its run.

In any case, the solution that worked for me was to get the [Scipy Superpack](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack). Much to my surprise, it worked! The README for the Superpack says that it needs Xcode 4.2, but I don't have that installed (I do have XCode 3.0). Now when I run IDLE, it says:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34)
```

and

```
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.7.0.dev-3f685a1'
>>> scipy.version.version
'0.11.0.dev-491f9db'
```

Since I found this thread as I was trying to find a solution, and posted my answer as soon as I got the above result, I don't know how well it works, but this does look like progress.

Comment: Hi thm, thank you very much. I couldn't import NumPy because I downloaded a wrong version of NumPy(numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg), it was for OS X 10.3, just as @talonmies said above. So I downloaded another version, it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey... this helped me a lot.. was struggling a bit.. :)